# Running an external program from an executable Jar

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jar

I have created a simple SWING gui for a cmd program someone else developed. To run this program I execute this line:

```
Process convertProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jlyt\\prog\\com_win\\jlyt.bat " + selectedFiles.getName());
```

The `jlyt` folder is in the same folder as my `src` folder (I am using IntelliJ).
When running via IDE everything works great, but not when I run the jar I created. I have tried running it from the directory it was saved to by IntelliJ as well as from the directory of the `jlyt` folder.
I did not add the external program (inside the `jlyt` folder) to my jar since it is very heavy. I want my jar to be distributed along side the original program and not to contain everything.

Any idea how I should build my jar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see why you put /jlyt in /src, it serves as a convenience within the IDE. /jlyt will get copied as a resource into /bin/classes, or whatever the IDE target is, and that allows everything to work from the IDE.

When you JAR your application, /jlyt is typically added to the JAR; however, it is not accessible to Windows. I assume you are placing a copy of /jlyt in the same folder as the JAR when you attempt to run.

As a first step, in a terminal, set the current directory to the folder containing the JAR and /jlyt. Since you are specifying a relative path in your exec(), that should be sufficient for everything to run.

You can also try creating a shortcut to the JAR, since it is executable, and set the working directory to the folder containing the JAR.

Comment: i didn't put /jlyt under /src specifically because i didnt want to add it to the jar. the folder /jlyt is in the same level as /src and I wanted to use relative path to it from the jar.
I actually excluded /jlyt when I created the jar

Comment: OK. Then the rest of what I said should apply. The main point is setting the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a relative path based on the place where jlyt.bat is according to your jar file.

e.g. use "./" or "../" to navigate the directory tree up.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the JAR file is only relevant for starting the JAR. The working directory must be the directory that contains the `jlyt` folder, since you are using 'jlyt\...' as path to the executable.

Example, lets suppose following directory structure:

> ```
> somewhere
>     project
>         gui
>             appl.jar
>         jlyt
>             prog
>                 ...
> ```

working directory must be 'project' and the JAR will then be referenced as 'gui\appl.jar

```
C:\somewhere> cd project
C:\somewhere\project> java -jar gui\appl.jar
```

Also be sure to wait for the convert process to terminate (e.g. `convertProcess.waitFor()`) before exiting your application/java - I believe that any running external process is killed when the Java Virtual Machine is closed!

Hint in documentation of Process:

> As of 1.5, ProcessBuilder.start() is the preferred way to create a Process.

Comment: If I follow your example, then appl.jar is actually in the same level as the jlyt directory, meaning they are both under project. This still didn't work. Maybe I need to edit the relative path to jlyt,bat? but what is missing?

Comment: @exigez  in my example, appl.jar is under "project*\gui*", that is, under "gui" which is under "project"... note the indentation, also note the cmd `java -jar gui\appl.jar` it clearly must be under gui